A curve on a graph of differentiable function is a differentiable curve?
My question is not on a specific question but on some concept I don't quite understand.
For example when we have that question:

Given that some man is standing on a hill which given by $$f(x,y)=\frac{40}{4+x^{2}+3y^{2}}$$ and he's standing at $(1,1,5)$, find the steepest way down from that given point

I know that we should take the curve that represent the man path (e.g. $\gamma (t)$) and give a restriction for the differential of $\gamma(t)$, I don't understand why we assuming $\gamma(t)$ is differentiable? it has some explanation or from the beginning it's our assumption that the path is differentiable?

How is defined the steepest way? And then $\gamma$? How does differentiability take place here?

It's for convenience. There's no reason why it should be differentiable. We assume it is so that we can use the methods from differential calculus

@mathcounterexamples.net
it's not formally defined but intuitively it's the path in each step we're going down as fast as we could on the graph of $f(x,y)$
we define $\gamma (t)$ as the path that satisfies that ($\gamma(0) = (1,1,5)$).
we need differentiability to give a condition for the differential of $\gamma$ to make sure that $\gamma (t)$ it's the steepest way as we desired (using the theorem from vector calculus about the gradient and it's relation for maximal / minimal direction for a given point.

@Dog_69
Ok then, it makes sense. Thank you.

@oneneedsanswers I remember a class of analysis where we were applying the methods of variational calculus. We started with a continuous Lagrangian that would represent something like the railways. The idea was to minimise the length. We also assume that the function was differentiable, to avoid stupid results. However, at some point, we differentiated twice to solve the equation. And the professor noticed that and said something like Actually, we don't know we found the minimal solution but only the minimal among the class of twice differentiable functions.  You have a similar scenario here

You just need to find the gradient of $f$ at said point. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient

@oneneedsanswers In fact, there is no reason for this steepest path to exist. It exists in our minds because we apply physical laws, mechanics in this case, and those rules are based on differentiability.

Thank you all for the answers! it really bothered me but now I understand what we've been looking for and why that's the answer.
